# What Meaning of 'over' here

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, vocabulary

What does 'over' mean in the following context?

> Ethernet describes how network devices format and transmit data so other devices on the same LAN or campus network can recognize, receive and process the information. An Ethernet cable is the physical, **encased wiring over which the data travels**.

Source: https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/definition/Ethernet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate word would be through in this case.

> encased wiring over which the data travels = encased wiring through which the data travels

This sentence is an inverted sentence.

> encased wiring over which the data travels = the data travels over encased wiring

Answer (score -1):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/over):

> *preposition*
> **4 c** —used as a function word to indicate a particular medium or channel of communication

In this case, "the physical, encased wiring" is the medium or channel of communication.